# How to select in cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I want to select the div with index 2 of in this Html with cheerio:

```
<div>..</div>
<div>..</div>
<div>..</div> //div index 2
<div>..</div>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pseudo-element `:nth-of-type(number)` to find that div. Your selector would look like this `div:nth-of-type(3)` and you could use in cheerio in the same way `$('div:nth-of-type(3)')`

Answer (score 0):

Use get method of cheerio

```
.get( [i] )
```

Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the Cheerio object. If an index is specified, retrieve one of the elements matched by the Cheerio object:

```
$('div').get(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const $ = cheerio.load('<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>');

$('div:nth-child(3)');
```

Having in mind that `nth-child` uses 1-based indexes.